# Vbs Excel formula for copying target's formula to current cell

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am using an ETL for APPENDING automatically some rows in Excel, but unfortunately there is no way to grab styles and formulae from previous rows.

So I decided to insert new rows with the following hardcoded formula/Value:

```
=CopyFormula(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```

And then design CopyFormula as a UDF that simply copies formula from the passed target cell

Why is not something like this working?

```
Public Function CopyFormula(rng As Range)
    rng.Copy Destination:=ActiveCell
    'ActiveCell.Formula = rng.Formula
    'return no value
End Function
```

I also tried copying and evaluating the neighbors formula, but unfortunately, evaluate() does not work when INDIRECT is present in the formula http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131384

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use a **Sub** rather than a **UDF**

**UDFs** in worksheet cells can only return values, not modify other cells.

Comment: Can a subroutine be called in a formula fashion? "=subroutine(x,y)". If not I am afraid I cannnot inject it from the ETL

Comment: By the way, I don't want to modify other cells, just the current one for which formula applies